# Siesta configuration 'self captured by a closure error'

Tags: swift, siesta

I am using Siesta framework and trying to add decorator in order to refresh token when it expires but I am getting: 'self captured by a closure before all members were initialized'.

What could be the reason?

```
service.configure("**") {
      $0.decorateRequests {
      self.refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: $1) // this line complains
    }
}
```

UPDATE

I found my problem and wanted to share it with you. The problem is related to services which were class properties:

```
class API: NSObject {

 private let service = Service(
    baseURL: myApiBaseUrl,
    standardTransformers: [.text, .json]
)

override init() {
    #if DEBUG
        // Bare-bones logging of which network calls Siesta makes:
        LogCategory.enabled = [.network]
    #endif

    service.configure("**") {

       $0.headers["Token"] = "Bearer \(token)"
       $0.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
       $0.headers["Accept"] = "application/json"

       $0.decorateRequests {
        self.refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: $1)
       }
    }
```

}

Instead of using a class property, I moved my service outside of the class and added a designated initializer.

```
init(myService:Service){
    super.init()

    myService.configure("**") {

        $0.headers["Token"] = "Bearer \(token)"
        $0.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        $0.headers["Accept"] = "application/json"

        $0.decorateRequests {
            self.refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: $1)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna add `[unowned self]`  at the beginning of the closure that way the the closure is not retained. Please try `[weak self ]` also

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Could you perhaps include this in OPs code, as to show how it is applied.

Comment: `service.configure("**") {[self unowned]
      $0.decorateRequests {
      self.refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: $1) // this line complains
    }
}`

Comment: Awesome, if you now edit your answer, I'd love to upvote it :)

Comment: Kunal when I add [self unowned] it is giving use of unresolved identifier for unowned

Comment: I tried this and it gives exactly the same error I got:
$0.decorateRequests {[unowned self] rep, req in
                self.refreshTokenOnAuthFailure(request: req)
            }

Comment: Thanks Kunal what you suggested worked after I create a custom init but I now have a different Siesta related issue.

Comment: @RandomSort I understood my mistake and I corrected it , thanks. Nice to meet you 

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what the problem is:

> error: 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized

You are trying to capture `self` before all members were initialized. Consider the following two examples, one shows the error you are having and the other doesn't.

## Example of your error

```
class Customer {

    var someProperty: String
    var someArray: [Int] = [1,2,3]

    init() {

        someArray.forEach {
            print("\($0): \(self.someProperty)") // Error: 'self' captured before initializing 'someProperty'
        }

        someProperty = "Potato"
    }
}

_ = Customer()
```

## Solution

```
class Customer {

    var someProperty: String
    var someArray: [Int] = [1,2,3]

    init() {

        someProperty = "Potato"

        someArray.forEach {
            print("\($0): \(self.someProperty)") // Good, 'someProperty' has been initialized already
        }
    }
}

_ = Customer()


// Output:
//
// 1: Potato
// 2: Potato
// 3: Potato
```